# Another way of show number of exclusive elements in a set

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

Sorry for any confusing. This is the first time I asked on this site, if there is any term that's wrongly used, please let me know

So given a diagram of A and B, to show exclusively A and exlusively B, we have

```
A or B - A and B
```

alternatively, we have

```
~ (A and B)
```

Then given A, B, C. To show exlusively A,exlusively B and exlusively C, we can do

```
A or B or C - A and B and C - A and B and not C - A and C and not B - B and C and not A
```

or

~ (A and B and C) - A and B and ~C - A and C and ~B - B and C and ~A

Then given A, B, C and D, we have

```
A or B or C or D - A and B and C and ~ D - A and B and D ~ C - A and D and C and ~ B - B and C and D and ~ A - A and B and ~ (C and D) - A and C and ~ (B and D) - A and D and ~ (B and C) - B and C and ~ (C and A) - C and D ~ (A and B)
```

I came up with above expression by drawing the van diagram. Is the above expression correct? Is there a better way to express this?

Comment: Are you asking for all the elements that are in one set but none of the others?  A notation for  $$\{x ~:~ \exists k ~ \forall j \ne k ~ (x \in S_k \land x \not \in S_j)\}$$

Comment: @DanielV is there a way to express it in term of A B C D? imagine you have A as American, B as British, C as Canadian and D as Dutch. Then there are a group of people. You are asked to find people who are purely American or purely British or purely Canadain and Purely Dutch, if that makes sense

Comment: I've can't remember or work out any compact way to say what you are describing.  The best I can come up with is $$\bigcup_k S_k - \bigcup_{j \ne k} S_j$$ where $S = \{A, B, C, D\}$